# Заставить фрагмент жить при использовании navController.navigate из android.arch.navigation

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation

При использовании любых методов навигации, NavController при переходе уничтожает фрагмент и его состояния, как задать ему поведение - не уничтожаться.

Comment: вы уверены, что вам это нужно? Это будет грузить память. Думаю, фрагмент можно сохранить в статическую переменную, и проверять если она не null, то использовать фрагмент из статики, иначе создать новый. Другой способ использовать pagerView - тогда фрагменты и листать можно будет. Но это в зависимости от абстоятельств

Comment: @Георгий Чеботарев статик сразу пропустим. 
те вы предлагаете обернуть всё во ViewPager, для того чтобы сохранялись фрагменты? и полностью избавиться от NavController, но вопрос прочтите пожалуйста внимательно.